# Time error when sending email SMTP with codeigniter - mediatemple hosting

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, time, smtp

I am sending emails from my website using codeigniters email helper (SMTP)

Emails are being delivered successfully to my inbox BUT I am receiving the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Los_Angeles' for 'PST/-8.0/no DST' instead

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 704
```

I have recently switched my hosting to mediatemple and haven't had messages like this before. Do I need to specify the time format somewhere or timezone??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `date.timezone` in your `php.ini` file and the warning should go away.

I believe MediaTemple allows you to edit your php.ini settings by including a php.ini in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the privileges to update php.ini (usually you don't),
you can add this line to your php script(s) :-

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore"); <-- replace to your desire city
```

There's more documentation on this function here: http://uk.php.net/date_default_timezone_set